# Strange type of union

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the strange title, I don't have much experience with SQL. I'm working with 2 tables : table `COMPONENTS`, that lists some components, and table `OPERATIONS` that is a list of operations applied to components.

Table `COMPONENTS` looks like that :

```
+-------+--------------+-------------------+-------+
| Level | Main Article | Secondary Article | Brand |
+-------+--------------+-------------------+-------+
|     1 | Article A    | Article 1         | Foo   |
|     1 | Article B    | Article 1         | Bar   |
+-------+--------------+-------------------+-------+
```

It has a lot more columns, but this is the idea. Basically it lists all articles in stock and what articles they are made of.

The `OPERATIONS`table contains all the operations a secondary article has to undergo to be incorporated into a main one :

```
+--------------------+-----------+------+
| Secondary Article  | Operation | Cost |
+--------------------+-----------+------+
| Article 1          | Cutting   | X    |
| Article 1          | Knitting  | Y    |
| Article 1          | Bleaching | Z    |
+--------------------+-----------+------+
```

What would be the best way to combine those two tables into one that would have this structure ?

```
+-------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+------+-------+
| Level | Main Article | Secondary Article | Operation | Cost | Brand |
+-------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+------+-------+
|     1 | Article A    | Article 1         |           |      | Foo   |
|     1 | Article A    | Article 1         | Cutting   | X    | Foo   |
|     1 | Article A    | Article 1         | Knitting  | Y    | Foo   |
|     1 | Article A    | Article 1         | Bleaching | Z    | Foo   |
|     1 | Article B    | Article 1         |           |      | Bar   |
|     1 | Article B    | Article 1         | Cutting   | X    | Bar   |
|     1 | Article B    | Article 1         | Knitting  | Y    | Bar   |
|     1 | Article B    | Article 1         | Bleaching | Z    | Bar   |
+-------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+------+-------+
```

I tried to simplify the problem as much as possible. How should I proceed to manage this ? I tried with joins and unions, but it doesn't work.

It seems to me that this would be super easy to do with a programming language that allows loops, but I'm completely lost here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a `UNION` I would do something like this:

```
SELECT C.Level,
       C.MainArticle,
       C.SecondaryArticle,
       O.Operation,
       O.Cost,
       C.Brand
FROM COMPONENTS C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(0),(1)) V(Header)
     LEFT JOIN OPERATIONS O ON V.Header = 1
                           AND C.SecondaryArticle = O.SecondaryArticle
ORDER BY C.MainArticle,
         V.Header,
         O.Cost;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d1557178a1f7ace57a5bb86e2a380b17)

Comment: It works almost like I want it to, thanks ! The stuff that doesn't work wasn't asked in my original question so I will figure it out by myself. Could you explain the purpose of CROSS APPLY and VALUES ? I've read some doc on CROSS and OUTER APPLY but can't figure out how it is used here.

Comment: It's creating an extra row here @ArnaudStephan , as there are 2 rows in the `VALUES` clause `0`, and `1`. I use `0` to denote the header and then only perform the `JOIN` to the table `OPERATIONS` when the row isn't a header. `VALUES` is exactly the same same as the `VALUES` construct in an `INSERT` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a `union all` with `join`:

```
select c.Level, c.MainArticle, c.SecondaryArticle, 
       NULL as operation, NULL as cost, c.brand
from components c
union all
select c.level, c.MainArticle, c.SecondaryArticle,
       o.operation, o.cost, c.brand
from components c join
     operations o
     on c.SecondaryArticle = o.SecondaryArticle;
```

If you care about the ordering in the result set, use:

```
order by MainArticle, SecondaryArticle
```

and whatever other keys you might want.

You could also do the `union all` *before* the `join`, although this might affect performance:

```
select c.level, c.MainArticle, c.SecondaryArticle,
       o.operation, o.cost, c.brand
from components c join
     ((select o.SecondaryArticle, o.operation, o.cost
       from operations o
      ) union all
      (select c.SecondaryArticle, NULL, NULL
       from components c
      )
     ) o
     on c.SecondaryArticle = o.SecondaryArticle;
```

Comment: Is the `union all` necessary? There are no duplicates.

Comment: @TheWildHealer . . . Yes.  One part get the original data from `components` with no price or operation and the other gets the data from `operations`.

Comment: Also, if you just use `UNION`, the data engine will check for duplicate rows @TheWildHealer. Just because you know there are no duplicates doesn't mean the data engine does.

Comment: Why are you doing `NULL as operation, NULL as cost, c.brand` ? Is there a need for two different NULL ?

Comment: The nulls are there to match the empty cells in your expected output. Thanks for your answer @Larnu

Answer (score 0):

Your `join`/`union` intuition was right, you can do something like this:

```
select
    Level,
    `Main Article`,
    `Secondary Article`,
    '' as Operation,
    '' as Cost,
    Brand
from
    COMPONENTS
union select
    COMPONENTS.Level,
    COMPONENTS.`Main Article`,
    COMPONENTS.`Secondary Article`,
    OPERATIONS.Operation,
    OPERATIONS.Cost,
    COMPONENTS.Brand
from
    COMPONENTS
    left join OPERATIONS on COMPONENTS.`Secondary Article` = OPERATIONS.`Secondary Article`
```

Comment: The OP stated that are using SQL Server, not MySQL. Backticks `\` ` aren't the quote identifier in T-SQL.